# Spring Boot with Hibernate Second Level cache

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, ehcache

I trying to use a second level cache so I put in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

in my application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

And I put to hibernate generate statistics

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=DEBUG
```

And in my Entity I put

```
@Entity(name = "natureza")
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class Natureza extends AbstractEntity{
...
}
```

But how can I see if my cache are realy working.

My hibernate log this:

```
2018-04-05 12:56:44.954 DEBUG 33410 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000117: HQL: SELECT * FROM natureza WHERE natureza_tipo_id = ?, time: 42ms, rows: 21 

2018-04-05 12:57:21.470 DEBUG 33410 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000117: HQL: SELECT * FROM natureza WHERE natureza_tipo_id = ?, time: 21ms, rows: 21

2018-04-05 12:57:40.938 DEBUG 33410 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000117: HQL: SELECT * FROM natureza WHERE natureza_tipo_id = ?, time: 27ms, rows: 21

2018-04-05 12:58:35.305 DEBUG 33410 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000117: HQL: SELECT * FROM natureza WHERE natureza_tipo_id = ?, time: 18ms, rows: 21

2018-04-05 12:59:04.187 DEBUG 33410 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000117: HQL: SELECT * FROM natureza WHERE natureza_tipo_id = ?, time: 14ms, rows: 21
```

so then I remove the cache from my app and the hibernate log this:

```
2018-04-05 13:02:38.883 DEBUG 34669 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000117: HQL: SELECT * FROM natureza WHERE natureza_tipo_id = ?, time: 50ms, rows: 21

2018-04-05 13:02:58.744 DEBUG 34669 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000117: HQL: SELECT * FROM natureza WHERE natureza_tipo_id = ?, time: 23ms, rows: 21

2018-04-05 13:03:13.570 DEBUG 34669 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000117: HQL: SELECT * FROM natureza WHERE natureza_tipo_id = ?, time: 12ms, rows: 21

2018-04-05 13:03:32.779 DEBUG 34669 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000117: HQL: SELECT * FROM natureza WHERE natureza_tipo_id = ?, time: 11ms, rows: 21

2018-04-05 13:03:59.771 DEBUG 34669 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000117: HQL: SELECT * FROM natureza WHERE natureza_tipo_id = ?, time: 7ms, rows: 21
```

So the hibernate are more slowly with the cache enabled :D

It`s possible to verify if the hibernate are creating the cached correctly? how? tks

Answer (score 1):

By logging "org.hibernate.cache" category in logger.

Answer (score 0):

You must map the ehcache in a "ehcache.xml" file (Resources folder)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>
 <cache
    name="path.ENTITY"
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300"
    timeToLiveSeconds="600"
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
 />
</ehcache>
```

info:
http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/integrations/hibernate.html

If you dont map the entity in the ehcache, you are not using it, that's why you see that times at the log.